# Send .zip file from service to nodejs app and after that to browser

Tags: node.js, web-services, binary, zip, buffer

I'm trying to send a zip file from Server(A) to Server(B)

***Browser***

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'routes/getFile',
        method: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
                 var byteCharacters = data;
                 var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
                 for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
                 } 
                 var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                 var blob1 = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/zip, application/octet-stream"});
                 var fileName1 = "cool.zip";
                 saveAs(blob1, "my.zip");
 }
```

***Server B (request the zip file)***

```
router.post('/getFile', (req, res, next) => { 
var options = {
    uri: 'Server_A_location'+ 'get_Zip',
    method: 'POST,
    json: req.body       
  }
 rp(options).then(function (data) {
     console.log(data)
     var buff = Buffer.from(data);
     res.send(buff);
 }
```

***Server A (here is the zip file)***

```
    var admzip=require('adm-zip')
    router.post('/get_Zip',function(req,res,next){
       var zip=new admZip();
       zip.addLocalFile('..path_of_zip_file');
       var zip_contents=zip.toBuffer();
       res.writeHead(200,{
                    'Content-Disposition':'attachment; filename="myfile.zip",
                    'Content-Type':'application/zip'
       })
       return res.end(zip_contents);
```

Data that i receive at ServerB is in binary format: PKYUQ�3�test1/test1.1.json�}kw⸲���+...

In browser I get the zip file but its broken. Any suggestions or ideas

Comment: just to make sure we're on the same page... `rp` stands for `request-promise` module in your case, right? So... let's say this zip weights 10MB. This way your service A loads 10MB into memory only to represent it as buffer and then writes it into the output... that multiplied by... 100 users already eats 1GB of memory just in zip, not counting all other resources that your app needs for other things...

Comment: what you need is to pipe the data stream so that you can spit out the bytes into the response as the come from the request. I guess it should be something like `res.setHeaders(....); rp(options).pipe(res); res.end()`. i haven't done this with express.js before, so you might need to dig around a little to find the right syntax for this really, but piping is definitely the way to go